# Ehcache element <cache/> does not allow attribute "transactionalMode"?

Tags: configuration, transactions, ehcache

According to the [Ehcache documentation](http://ehcache.org/documentation/jta.html), starting with version 2.0, an Ehcache cache may participate in a [JTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Transaction_API) transaction based on the value of attribute `transactionalMode` on element `<cache/>`.

If this is true, then why does Ehcache, when it encounters this attribute in my Ehcache configuration file, throw the following exception and complain that "Element  does not allow attribute "transactionalMode".":

```
Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Error configuring from zip:C:/Program Files/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/abstrack1/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/_appsdir_middleware-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT_ear/n8rga7/middleware-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/ehcache.xml. Initial cause was Error configuring from input stream. Initial cause was null:35: Element <cache> does not allow attribute "transactionalMode".
    at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory.parseConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:95)
    at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory.parseConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:131)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.parseConfiguration(CacheManager.java:241)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:190)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:183)
    at net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider.start(EhCacheProvider.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1291)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:814)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:732)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1369)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
    ... 76 more]]>
```

Here is a sample cache definition from my `ehcache.xml` file in which I've set `transactionalMode` to "xa":

```
<cache
    name="com.db.spgit.abstrack.model.Security"
    maxElementsInMemory="500"
    eternal="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="300"
    timeToLiveSeconds="86400"
    overflowToDisk="false"
    transactionalMode="xa" />
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you sure you have ehcache v2+ in your classpath? Maybe you have two versions by accident, perhaps your Hibernate dependency has one included?

Comment: Skaffman, you are right! Hibernate 3.3.2.GA with Ehcache integration has included Ehcache 1.2.3 and I explicitly included Ehcache 2.1.0 (and then 2.2.0).  Do you happen to know which version of Hibernate supports (requires) Ehcache 2.0 or later?

Comment: Altneratively, how can I prevent Maven from including Ehcache 1.2.3 and instead use Ehcache 2.2.0 with Hibernate Ehcache 3.3.2GA (depends on Ehcache 1.2.3) or 3.5.1-Final (depends on Ehcache 1.5.0)?  Feel free to put your comments in your answer to my question.

Comment: I've promoted the question in my second comment to a question of its own at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561235/how-can-i-force-maven-to-use-hibernate-3-3-2ga-with-ehcache-2-2-0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that Maven had also included [Ehcache 1.2.3](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache/1.2.3) in my project EAR file because [Hibernate Ehcache Integration 3.3.2.GA](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-ehcache/3.3.2.GA) requires Ehcache 1.2.3.

Answer (score 0):

that means that you need to remove the transitive dependency ehcache 1.2.3.jar and leave include 2.X version .  need to see if that has no problem working with hibernate 3.2.X though.