# How can I force Maven to use Ehcache 2.2.0 with Hibernate 3.3.2GA?

Tags: hibernate, maven-2, ehcache

Assuming that the two are compatible, how can I force Maven 2 to use [Ehcache 2.2.0](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache/2.2.0) instead of [Ehcache 1.2.3](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache/1.2.3) with [Hibernate 3.3.2.GA](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/3.3.2.GA)?

Essentially, I wish to replace the puzzling and practically cyclic dependency chain

- [Hibernate Ehcache Integration 3.3.2.GA](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-ehcache/3.3.2.GA) => [Ehcache 1.2.3](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache/1.2.3) => [Hibernate 3.2.0.cr3](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate/3.2.0.cr3) => [Ehcache 1.2](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ehcache/ehcache/1.2)

with

- [Hibernate Ehcache Integration 3.3.2.GA](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-ehcache/3.3.2.GA) => [Ehcache 2.2.0](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache/2.2.0)

**Update:**

I learned that `hibernate-commons-annotations-3.3.0.ga` also depends on artifact `ehcache-1.2.3`:

```
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.3.0.ga:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.2.1.ga:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- asm:asm-attrs:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.1_3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- asm:asm:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0:compile
```

What is the purpose of `hibernate-commons-annotations-3.3.0.ga`?  Does Hibernate need this artifact if it uses `hibernate-annotations-3.2.1-ga`? Is there a replacement for this artifact that doesn't include Ehcache? Should I simply try to exclude it from the build?

Comment: It's seems that hibernate-commons-annotations-3.3.0.ga.jar depends on the monolithic hibernate-3.2.1.ga.jar that had ehcache as dependency at this time. I don't use these dependencies, I only depend on hibernate-entitymanager-3.4.0.GA.jar. I'll show my pom and the dependency tree.

Comment: But whatever dependencies you use, you can always exclude it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Assuming that the two are compatible, how can I force Maven 2 to use Hibernate 3.3.2.GA with Ehcache 2.2.0? According to their respective Maven POM files:

I've investigated this question for my personal needs and I have now concrete answers. All the required informations are available online and I'm just posting a very short  version of *howto use Ehcache 2.x with Hibernate 3.3+*.

First, you need to declare the dependency on the ehcache artifact.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
  <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Then, configure Hibernate for second level caching and specify the second level cache provider:

```
<property key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
```

Important things to note:

- we are using the property for *the new Hibernate 3.3/3.5 SPI* (that Ehcache 2.0+ supports)

  - **`hibernate.cache.region.factory_class`**
- we are using the cache provider **provided by Echache**

  - **`net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory`** (and not `o.h.c.EhCacheProvider`)

So you actually just don't need the [`hibernate-ehcache`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-ehcache/3.3.2.GA) artifact - and this solves the entire question :) Here are the exact (relevant) dependencies I use:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
  <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

And the tree:

```
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.4.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:ejb3-persistence:jar:1.0.2.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.1.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.4.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.3.0.SP1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- javassist:javassist:jar:3.4.GA:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:0.9.18:compile
[INFO] |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:0.9.18:compile
[INFO] \- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:pom:2.2.0:compile
[INFO]    +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO]    +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-terracotta:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO]    \- org.terracotta:terracotta-toolkit-1.0-runtime:jar:1.0.0:compile
```

For more details, ehcache configuration samples, official documentation, refer to the links below.

#### Resources

- [Ehcache 2.0 supports new Hibernate 3.3 caching provider](http://relation.to/Bloggers/Ehcache20SupportsNewHibernate33CachingProvider)
- [Configure Ehcache as a Second Level Cache](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ConfigureEhcacheasaSecondLevelCache)
- [Hibernate Second Level Cache](http://ehcache.org/documentation/hibernate.html)
- [Upgrading From Ehcache versions prior to 2.0](http://ehcache.org/documentation/hibernate-upgrade.html)

Comment: I see!  Will give this a try and let you know my results.  Does this also apply to Hibernate 3.5+?

Comment: I re-read your answer and noticed that your first note suggests that this solution also works for Hibernate 3.5+.

Comment: @Derek Yes it does, as stated in the first note :)

Comment: Pascal, I discovered that artifact `hibernate-commons-annotations-3.3.0.ga` also pulls in `ehcache-1.2.3` (see update in my question).

Comment: Here is the updated URL for [Upgrading From Ehcache versions prior to 2.0](http://ehcache.org/documentation/integrations/hibernate-upgrade). @Pascal, I tried editing your answer but SO complained about improper code indentation and I wasn’t able to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

You can exclude Ehcache 1.2.3 dependency using "exclude" element, see http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html, section *Dependency Exclusions*. But I do not know if it works. I do not know if Ehcache is back compatible with 1.2.3. The number of the version suggests it is not. But with "exclude" you can remove Ehcache 1.2.3 and 1.5.0 dependences easily.

Comment: I used element `<exclusions/>` to exclude `ehcache-1.2.3` from the list of dependencies for `hibernate-commons-annotations-3.3.0.ga` since I think Hibernate annotations requires this artifact.