# NoClassDefFoundError with new EHCache config

Tags: java, caching, ehcache, noclassdeffounderror

I have a Java class that has a static implementation that fetches cache configuration and instantiate it like below:

```
import net.sf.ehcache.Cache;
import net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager;
import net.sf.ehcache.Element;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.net.URL;

public final class MyCacheImplementation {

    private MyCacheImplementation() {
        super();
    }

    private static Cache myCache;

    private static final String EHCACHFILENAME = "....... ehcache.xml";

    static {
        try {
            final URL url = MyCacheImplementation.class.getClassLoader().getResource(EHCACHFILENAME);
            final CacheManager cacheManager = new CacheManager(url);
            myCache = cacheManager.getCache("myCacheName);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error initializing Ehcache", e);
        }
    }

    public static void addItemToCache(final Object obj) {       
        myCache.put(new Element("obj1234", obj));       
    }

    public static Cache getMyCache() {
        return myCache;
    }

}
```

I then have a class that reference the above class in a static way and queries the cache like below:

```
final MyCacheImplementation cacheReference = MyCacheImplementation.getMyCache();
```

My cache configuration looks like below:

```
<ehcache>   
    <defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="10000" eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="120" timeToLiveSeconds="120" overflowToDisk="true"
        diskPersistent="false" diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120" />

    <cache name="myCacheName" maxElementsInMemory="1000"
        eternal="false" overflowToDisk="false" timeToIdleSeconds="18000"
        diskPersistent="false"
        timeToLiveSeconds="18000" />
</ehcache>
```

Everything works as expected and I can access the cache this way.

Then we upgraded our EHCache Version to 2.9  and switched off disc stores aka 
changing the above config to look like:

```
<ehcache>
    <defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="10000" timeToIdleSeconds="120" timeToLiveSeconds="120">
        <persistence strategy="none" />
    </defaultCache>

    <cache name="myCacheName" maxElementsInMemory="1000" timeToIdleSeconds="18000" timeToLiveSeconds="18000">
        <persistence strategy="none" />
    </cache>
</ehcache>
```

Now if I run the same thing as above i get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class NoClassDefinition error. If I roll back the EHCache config to what it was it works perfectly. Any idea what could be wrong with this config? I have serveral other places in our code where the config is exactly the same and that is not causing any issues?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the error you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the actual exception was swallowed.

The exception was when the cached was trying to be initialized with the following error message:

```
ehcache Element <defaultCache> does not allow nested <persistence> elements
```

Turns out that I had a trasitive dependency to an old version of EHCache pulled in by Hibernate caching, as explained by [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560659/ehcache-element-cache-does-not-allow-attribute-transactionalmode)